# Настройка PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Как настроить pycharm таким образом, чтобы при вставке обычного текста, текст не выходил за положенную рамку, происходил автоматический перенос строки?

(Уйти от скрола в правую сторону и ручного переноса).

(Либо, грубо говоря, закрепить границу и сделать невозможным переход через неё)
Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Перейдите ***File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style***
2. Поставьте галочку напротив ***Wrap on Typing***
3. Теперь переносы будут осуществляться после нажатия на пробел, если ваша строка превысила максимальную длину указанную в графе ***Hard wrap at***.

Замечание:

1. обратите внимание, что перенос осуществляется целыми словами, они не делятся на слоги.
2. Работа протестирована на версии PyCharm 2020.2

Comment: К сожалению, это не рабочий вариант, потому что на вставку он не влияет (текст все равно вставляется в одну строку) / ограничений нет

Comment: Оказалось все намного проще. Часть Вашего ответа может быть использована, но как дополнение. Остальное получил при штудировании JetBrains, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-editor-general.html

Comment: У меня оно работает и на вставку. Необходимо лишь несколько раз нажать пробел

Comment: да. такое тоже есть, но если один элемент списка состоит из нескольких слов, то перенос происходит неправильно, например, мы вставляем список, состоящий из нескольких предложений: ['python python python', 'python python python'.......], то на выходе после преобазований через вышеописанную функцию получаем ['python python', 'python', 'python'...], т.е. происходит дополнительно разделение уже имеющегося предложения в списке запятыми.

Comment: У меня разделение запятыми отсутствует. Перенос идет не по PEP8, но он способен автоматически отформатироваться, либо вы можете отформатировать руками
[Пример как выглядит у меня](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTUXM.png).


Опять же, вопросе указано, что необходима вставка обычного текста, а не специальных типов данных

Comment: @ДимаВиноградов AlexElizard правильно описал, вроде все работает правильно, а при большой вставке, можно нажать пробел и слова будут перенесены на следующую строку ( Посмотрите на скрин повнимательней, там происходит не разделение массива на новые элементы одного элемента на несколько строк, после чего он собирается сложением строк), мол ["Привет""мир", " Как дела?"] - тут 2 элемента в массиве, а не 3